# Why am I getting such an error using keyword of MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table name : Scores**

**Code:**

```
select s1.score 

from Scores s1
order by DESC;
```

**Error :**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC' at line 5
```

Comment: You need a column or expression for the `order by`.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE scores: for analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to mention which column name you want to `Order By`. You are missing the column name and that what the error is. try the following.

```
select s1.score 
from Scores s1
order by 
  score DESC;
```